# Sublime Text, Pandoc, and exporting Markdown to PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, sublimetext3, sublimetext, pandoc

So, I have Sublime Text set up with the [pandoc package](https://github.com/tbfisher/sublimetext-Pandoc). When I try to export a markdown file (with a .md extension) to PDF using this package, I get the following error:

`Fail to generate output. Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

When I use pandoc from the command line, it generates a PDF just fine. So I'm assuming this is an issue with the package. When I use the pandoc package to generate things that aren't PDFs, like html or docx, it works just fine. Anyone know what I've got wrong?

For reference, my pandoc package user settings:

```
{
  "default": {

    "pandoc-path": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Pandoc/pandoc.exe",

    "transformations": {

      "HTML 5": {
        "scope": {
          "text.html.markdown": "markdown"
        },
        "syntax_file": "Packages/HTML/HTML.tmLanguage",
        "pandoc-arguments": [
          "-t", "html",
          "--to=html5",
          "--no-highlight", 
        ]
      },

      "PDF": {
        "scope": {
          "text.html": "html",
          "text.html.markdown": "markdown"
        },
        "pandoc-arguments": [
          "-t", "pdf", 
          "-s", "--toc", "--number-sections",
        "--variable", "geometry:margin=1.25in",
        "-t", "pdf",
           "--latex-engine=C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9",
        ]
      },

  "Microsoft Word": {
    "scope": {
      "text.html": "html",
      "text.html.markdown": "markdown"
    },
    "pandoc-arguments": [
      "-t", "docx",
      "-s", "--toc", "--number-sections"
    ]
  },

    },
    "pandoc-format-file": ["docx", "epub", "pdf", "odt", "html"]

  }

}
```

Comment: if you just want to generate pdf from markdown, just write your own build system.

Comment: If it is possible, also try to pinpoint the part of markdown which is causing the problem.